# I can't upload large files to nginx running a flask application

Tags: python, nginx, flask, file-upload, gunicorn

I want to upload any size file up to 120Gb via flask on my server.
Currently I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.
Also, sometimes a part of the file is uploaded but never the whole file when the size is above 2Gb.

However, when I upload the file to the Flask debug server, it works (I even tried with a 100Gb file and it worked).

I have changed the nginx configuration very often and tested results from the web, none helped.

The important part of my `nginx.conf` file

```
http {

        client_max_body_size 200G;
        client_body_timeout 3h;

        client_body_in_file_only clean;
        client_body_buffer_size 16k;
        client_body_temp_path /home/nginx/client_body_temp;


        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        
}
```

My server nginx configuration

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;


    server_name _;


    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}



server {
    listen 443;
    server_name cloudster.online www.cloudster.online 85.214.69.4;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /home/cloudster/Release/data/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/cloudster/Release/data/privatekey.key;


    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off;


    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass https://unix:/home/cloudster/Release/cloudster.sock;

        proxy_max_temp_file_size 100000m;
        proxy_temp_path /home/nginx/client_body_temp;
        proxy_store off;
        proxy_cache off;
    }
}
```

And my service configuartion file

```
[Unit]
Description=Cloudster executed by Gunicorn
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/cloudster/Release
Environment="PATH=/home/cloudster/Release/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/cloudster/Release/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --workers 50 \
          --bind unix:cloudster.sock -m 007 \
          wsgi:app \
          --keyfile data/privatekey.key \
          --certfile data/cert.crt \
          --worker-class=gevent \
          --graceful-timeout=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I hope someone could help me.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: yes, I don't know exactly which setting it was, but I think the connection was cutted before done, but now I'm using chunked upload and it works.

Comment: Thanks. In my case it was actually not nginx issue but underlying gunicorn app. I had to set longer timeout in gunicorn.